# Referencing Supplemental Material for Physical Review Letters

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex, back-referencing

I have been working on an manuscript to submit for publication at Physical Review Letters. For it, I am using there recommended package: [REVTeX 4.2e](https://journals.aps.org/revtex). The manuscript has a two parts: the "main part" which contains the main discussion of the paper and the "supplemental part" which has the supplemental materials.

**Goal:** What I want to do is to refer to the supplemental part from the main part for a derivation of an equation so the in the bibliography section of the "main part", it reads the following as instructed [here](https://journals.aps.org/authors/supplemental-material-instructions):

> See Supplemental Material at [URL will be inserted by publisher] for [give brief description of material].

**My Attempts:** The way I have achieved this is as follows. Inside the `main.tex`, I write:

```
% main.tex
...is given by $E = \gamma mc^2$~\cite{[{See Supplemental Material at }][{ for the derivation of this equation.}]supp}.
% supp is the citation key for the supplemental part.
```

And inside the `bibliography.bib` file, I write:

```
@misc{supp,
author = {},
title = {},
howpublished = "\url{URL_will_be_inserted_by_publisher}",
year = {},
note = " "}
```

With these at hand, when I compile I get the desired output:

> See  Supplemental  Material  at URL_will_be_inserted_by_publisher for the derivation of this equation.

**My Question:** Is it the correct way to do this referencing? Or, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: My interpretation of the instructions would be to use a simple citation to "supp" (no brackets/etc.) in the text. In the reference list, that reference number should be as stated, so you want something more like @misc{supp, note = "See Supplemental Material at URL_will_be_inserted_by_publisher for the derivation of this equation."}. (You might also need blank author, title, and/or year fields to make sure there are no BibTeX errors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the bibliography file, add an entry

  ```
  @misc{supp,
    note = "See Supplemental Material at
      URL-will-be-inserted-by-publisher for the data
      of the experiments."
  }
  ```

  Replace `the data of the experiments` by whatever the supplemental material actually is.
  URL-will-be-inserted-by-publisher has to be replaced as soon as the supplemental materials has got a fixed URL.
- In the paper, at an appropriate place, add an ordinary reference using `\cite{supp}`.

Here is an example, first the output and then the LaTeX code.

[image]

The output above was obtained by storing the text below as `main.tex` and `myreferences.bib`, respectively, and running `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and `pdflatex`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
The Supplemental Material Instructions by the Physical Review Journals read:
\begin{quote}
  Authors should ensure that the journal article contains a single
  numbered reference in the reference list using this format:\\\relax
  [20] See Supplemental Material at [URL will be inserted by publisher]
  for [give brief description of material].\\
  and that the reference number is cited in the main text.
\end{quote}
So, this means that somewhere in the paper, we reference the
supplemental material~\cite{supp} that we have prepared, like I
just did.  The text ``See Supplemental Material at [URL will be
inserted by publisher] for [give brief description of material]'' goes
into the note-field of the bib entry, see myreferences.bib.
\bibliography{myreferences}
\end{document}


% myreferences.bib
@misc{supp,
  note = "See Supplemental Material at
    URL-will-be-inserted-by-publisher for the data
    of the experiments."
}
```